# How to randomly select three points in each polygon?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I have two layers: first layer includes polygons of districts, second layer containts points (phytocoenological relevées).

The goal is to create a new layer that will contain max 3 randomly selected phytocoenological relevées belonging to one district area (now, particular district contain 0-16 relevées).

I went through all QGIS vector selection tools but was not successfull in it..

Comment: did you take a look at the [How to randomly select from existing points within each polygon](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85254/how-to-randomly-select-from-existing-points-within-each-polygon)

Comment: The post @MDHald mentioned sounds like it could do what you're looking for. Just to add that you could also use the **intersect** tool with your point layer as the _input layer_ and then run the **Random selection within subsets**.